# How to remove or replace a pattern at the beginning of a string with Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to remove the first dash of this string XXXXX-080-YYYYT If my string starts with `XXX` or `YUO` or `TRRYTY` or `TRTR`, in order to get a string that looks like `XXXXX080-YYYYT` with Powershell. If I don't remove the dash and I keep `XXXXX-080-YYYYT`. Regardless of the length of the word, my goal is to remove the first dash. This a 20200925.csv:

```
function Remove-FirstDashOnMatch{
        [cmdletbinding()]
        param(
            [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
            [string[]]
            $ElementCsv="$20200925.csv",
    
            [Parameter()]
            [string[]]
            $Terms = @()
        )
        begin {
            # create the regex patterns from terms
            $patterns = $Terms | ForEach-Object {'(^' +  $_ + '\S+?)-' }
        }
    
        process{
                        # Import the  contents of the 20200925-01.csv and Create ElementCsv object
 $ElementCsv=Import-csv  $Extract_20200925.csv -Delimiter ';'
#Loop through all the record in the CSV file
$NewModifiedElement= ForEach($Entry in $ElementCsv){
        
        if ($Entry."Script or expected file(s)" -ilike 'technical') {
                $Entry.Jobstream=$Entry.Jobstream.trimStart('PCLD')
        }else {
                # Get the name of jobSet without extension .ksh ou .bat
                $Entry.Jobstream=$Entry."Script or expected file(s)"
                $pos_last_point = $Entry.Jobstream.LastIndexOf(".")
                #Write-Host $pos_last_point
                $Entry.Jobstream = $Entry.Jobstream.Substring(0,$pos_last_point).trimStart('P')  
                $matchObj = $Entry.Jobstream | Select-String -Pattern $patterns
                $Entry.Jobstream -replace $matchObj.Pattern, '$1'

        }
        
        $Entry
}
# Export 20200925-01.csv in new 20200925-02.csv file 
$NewModifiedElement | Export-Csv "20200925-mesurecommand.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
}
    }
Remove-FirstDashOnMatch # Call the function
```

How remove the first dash in String?

Comment: Looks like you insist on removing certain information. Please be aware that you are not supposed to vandalise your posts (and usually such changes are undone). Also that removing information which answers are based on is unfair, as it makes the answers look weirdly non-applicable and/or eerily clairvoyant. Also, the information you remove is still visible in the histoty. If you edit because information is sensitive then you need to contact a moderator to help you with actually and effectively removing it, you yourself cannot. Same by the way for others of your posts.

Comment: Stop destroying the answers given on your original question! If you have a new question, then post it as a new one, do not try to alter anything here!

Comment: @Theo For such an old question, and based on your understanding of the technical details (which I lack), I am with you if you undo the edit. Just think twice whether there is any chance that the edit was meant to or is actually improving the question. Either just roll back or edit to keep the improvements while also the core which the answers address.

Answer (score 3):

```
# Add some data for example
$data = @'
XXXXX-080-YYYY
WEBXX-080-YYYY
XXXXX-080-YYYY
DOCXXX-080-YYYY
DWHSXXX-080-YYYY
CLOTXsdff-080-YYYY
'@ -split '\r?\n'


# function to remove first dash if match on term
function Remove-FirstDashOnMatch {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string[]]
        $InputObject,

        [Parameter()]
        [string[]]
        $Terms = @('WEBX', 'DWHS', 'COGN', 'CLOT', 'CLAI')
    )
    begin {
        # create the regex patterns from terms
        $patterns = $Terms | ForEach-Object {'(^' +  $_ + '\S+?)-' }
    }

    process {
        foreach ($input in $InputObject) {
            # check if string matches any pattern
            if ($matchObj = $input | Select-String -Pattern $patterns) {
                # if match, use replace to remove the '-'
                $input -replace $matchObj.Pattern, '$1'
            }
            else {
                $input
            }
        }
    }
}


# Use function
$data | Remove-FirstDashOnMatch
```

Output

```
XXXXX-080-YYYY
WEBXX080-YYYY
XXXXX-080-YYYY
DOCXXX-080-YYYY
DWHSXXX080-YYYY
CLOTXsdff080-YYYY
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`-creplace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-operator) and a multiline regex. You should also use `-Raw` for efficiency.

```bash
# use `-replace` instead for case insensitive
(Get-Content 'path/to/file.example' -Raw) -creplace '(?m)^(WEBX|DWHS|COGN|CLOT|CLAI)-', '$1'
```

See https://regex101.com/r/B5Yjvl/1 for regex details.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my two cents:

```
$strArray = 'XXXXX-080-YYYYT','WEBXF-080-YYYYT','DWHSG-080-YYYYT','YYYYY-080-YYYYT','CLAIX-080-YYYYT',
            'CLOTS-080-YYYYT','XZXZX-080-YYYYT','ABABA-080-YYYYT','COGNI-080-YYYYT','XXZXX-080-YYYYT'

# use -cmatch if the comparison should be Case-Sensitive
$strArray | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^(WEBX|DWHS|CLAI|CLOT|COGN)') { ($_ -split '-', 2) -join '' }
    else { $_ }
}
```

Output:

```
XXXXX-080-YYYYT
WEBXF080-YYYYT
DWHSG080-YYYYT
YYYYY-080-YYYYT
CLAIX080-YYYYT
CLOTS080-YYYYT
XZXZX-080-YYYYT
ABABA-080-YYYYT
COGNI080-YYYYT
XXZXX-080-YYYYT
```

Comment: @Bankass Well, that is to be expected, since you have now changed the question completely from what it was. Originally you had **strings** to deal with. Now you show us you are processing a CSV file with mutiple values in different columns. Still no big deal to do, but you should have made that clear in the first place. Now, all three answers given had no previous knowledge of the CSV file.. Not just that, but your sample string ` XXXXX-080-YYYYT` is absolutely nowhere to be found in the csv you have added. Nothing even comes close to that.